# UI testing ListView, getting count and specific item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I am able create a UI Test for ListView on iOS. However, the same code doesn't work on Android.

On iOS, list count is what I expect to be in the list. On Android, the list count is +1. I am also not able to get the data from the list at a particular position.

Below, is my code that works well for iOS, but is not working for Android.

Is it possible that same script that is working for iOS may not work for Android?

```
//count the number of child in the list

Assert.That(app.Query(x => 
    x.Marked("AutomationId_ProfileVehicleList").Child()).Length, Is.EqualTo(3));

//get the data from list and match

Assert.AreEqual(app.Query(c => c.Id("AutomationId_ProfileVehicle"))[0].Text, 
     "KA123C3");
```

Comment: You are not unit testing, you are using a unit test framework to make UI tests. Not quite the same, I have helped you by editing your question to reflect this... Anyways, there will be cases, where you will need to do platform specific tests. Since, under the hood Android will use a RecyclerView while iOS will use a CollectionView, which function differently. It is unclear from your question, but there could be off-screen items, which could show up in your result. As for getting the specific item, look at the view hierarchy and determine whether the correct item has the automation id.

Comment: @Cheesebaron thanx, i found the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

//get the list count and use id of entry

```
       Assert.That(app.Query(x => x.Marked("AutomationId_ProfileVehicle")).Length, Is.EqualTo(3));
```

//get the data from list and match

```
       Assert.AreEqual(app.Query(x => x.Marked("AutomationId_ProfileVehicle"))[0].Text, "KA123C3");
```

this worked for me, instead of id, i used Marked

Comment: I tried the first line of code with a `CollectionView` instead of a `ListView` and it doesn’t work: it still shows only one element.